# Get the name or label from django IntegerChoices providing a valid value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have django 3.2 and an IntegerChoices class

```
 class Type(models.IntegerChoices):
        GENERAL = 2, _("general address")
        DELIVERY = 4, _("delivery address")
        BILLING = 6, _("billing address")
```

I can get the Value name and label easily by doing Type.GENERAL , Type.GENERAL.name and Type.GENERAL.label.

But how can I get these values if I only have the value, e.g. I want to get the Name DELIVERY from the value 4.

Type[4].name ist not working as the list values does not correspond to the int values of the enum.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IntegerChoices.choices` returns you a list of tuples with all content. In your case you'll have something like:

```
[(2, 'general address'), (4, 'delivery address'), (6, 'billing address')]
```

Thus it can be done this way:

```py
class Type(models.IntegerChoices):
    GENERAL = 2, _("general address")
    DELIVERY = 4, _("delivery address")
    BILLING = 6, _("billing address")

def label_by_type_value(value):
    choices = [c[1] for c in Type.choices if c[0] == value]
    return choices[0] if len(choices) else None
```

Comment: Yes this I have already seen, I thougth there is an build-in way to do that. Maybe the use case is too rare for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this if you can be sure that it is a valid value:

```
print(Type(2).name)    
print(Type(2).label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest failing fast and terminating the moment you have a match over the list comprehension with length checking:

```py
def label_of_choice_value(choice_type: Type[Choices], search_value) -> str:
    """Given a type that inherits from Choice and a value, returns the label associated with that value in the choice type.
    :return: The label associated with the value
    :raises:
        StopIteration: if the value is not present
    """
    return next(label for value, label in choice_type.choices if value == search_value)
```

Then, the calling code can decide if it considers no matches an exception or not by catching StopIteration.